# How to divide an HTML page into 3 columns, which can be scrolled like a list independently of each other

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I need to divide the HTML page into 3 columns so that the content in each of them can be scrolled through separately. The page itself should be static, that is, only the columns are scrolled and that’s it. Here is a screenshot of the Apple notes from which I take an example: in the first column there are folders and you can scroll through them, in the second there are notes in the folder and you can also scroll through them independently, and the third static field will contain text.
[image]

I haven’t tried anything yet, because I don’t know if it’s even possible. Send links to the form at least or briefly tell me if it is possible or not and how

Answer (score 4):

You hide the overflow of body, you use 3 divs to divide the screen and display `overflow-y` for them:

```js
let content = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    content.push(i);
}
content = content.join("<br>");
for (let c of document.querySelectorAll(".main-content")) {
    c.innerHTML = content;
}
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.main-content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 31%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#left {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

#center {
    background-color: gray;
}

#right {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="left" class="main-content"></div>
<div id="center" class="main-content"></div>
<div id="right" class="main-content"></div>
```